# How to show each of the selected value from multiple select option in input tag

Tags: reactjs

I am new react.I try to show value of select tag to input text but I want to display foodState and size separated by commas in same input text and  (example:  Steak,L )
I don't know how to coding it
please help me

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
function App() {
  const [foodState, setFoodState] = useState("");
  const [size, setSize] = useState("");

  return (
    <div className="container p-5">
      <select
        className="custom-select"
        value={foodState}
        onChange={(e) => {
          const selectedFood = e.target.value;
          setFoodState(selectedFood);
        }}
      >
        <option value="steak">Steak</option>
        <option value="sandwich">Sandwich</option>
        <option value="dumpling">Dumpling</option>
      </select>

      <select
        className="custom-select"
        value={size}
        onChange={(e) => {
          const selectedprice = e.target.value;
          setSize(selectedprice);
        }}
      >
        <option value="S">S</option>
        <option value="M">M</option>
        <option value="L">L</option>
      </select>
                   <Input
                        name="Bill1"
                        type="text"
                        value={foodState}
                        />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you expecting something like this ?
inside Input try

```
value={`${foodState} ,${size}`}
```